# Referencing Appendices in MLA Style

Tags: citations, mla, appendix

I have multiple appendices containing the transcriptions of interviews that I carried out as part of my research. How do I cite these appendices in MLA style? 
I can't seem to find any consistent examples online.
Do I just use something simple like (Appendix A)? Or can I include a page number such as (Appendix A, page 3)? Could I possibly include the interviewee's name (O'Connell, Appendix A, page 3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page 70 of the *MLA Handbook* (8th ed.), it says:

> Words designating the divisions of a work are also not italicized or put in quotation marks, nor are they capitalized when used in the text ("The author says in her preface . . .," "In canto 32 Ariosto writes . . .").
>
> preface                     chapter 2
> introduction               bibliography
> list of works cited     canto 32
> appendix                   act 4
> scene 7                    index
> stanza 20

This at least indicates you should be using lowercase roman text.

In order to maintain consistency with this, if you have multiple appendices, I would recommend using numbers rather than letters:

> Smith says that . . . (See appendix 2.)

If you actually use page numbers in the appendices, I see no reason why you can't refer to them. But unless you have multiple interview subjects in a single appendix (and on the same page), I can't see a need to mention the person's name in the citation—as opposed to in the running text itself:

> Smith says that . . . (See appendix 2, page 4.)

In looking at this, the actual method of introducing the reference may be a bit tricky—because you're actually referring to your *own* work rather than someone else's, and probably want to avoid the use of the first person. Also, you may want to use a citation style as reference (as in your question) rather than a sentence style. In which case, *Appendix* would start with a capital letter anyway.

Whatever you do, just make sure you do it consistently.